# Error with jquery ajax send

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I send a contact form with jquery ajax and the informations not successful sent.
and the fields [object HTMLInputElement] error in email
please help me

form code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".buttonmh").click(function() {
        var dataString = 'namet=' + namet + '&emailt=' + emailt + '&phonet=' + phonet + '&massaget=' + massaget;
        //alert (dataString);return false;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "send.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function() {
                $('#contact-formm').html("<div id='messagee'></div>");
                $('#messagee').html("<h2>The new message was sent!</h2>")
                    .append("")
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn(1500, function() {
                        $('#messagee').append("");
                    });
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
<form action="" id="contact-form" class="main-contacts">
    <div id="messagee" class="error-sus" style="background:green; color:#fff;text-align:left;direction:ltr;"></div>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="col1">
            <div class="rowElem">
                <div class="bg">
                    <input type="text" name="namet" id="namet" value="<?php echo ContactName ;?>:" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Name:'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Name:' ) this.value=''">
                </div>
                <label class="error" for="namet" id="name_error">
                    <?php echo RequiredFieldMessage ;?>
                </label>
                <label class="error" for="namet" id="name_error2">
                    <?php echo NotValidValueMessage ;?>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="emailt" id="emailt" value="<?php echo ContactEmail ;?>:" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='E-mail:'" onFocus="if(this.value =='E-mail:' ) this.value=''">
                <input type="text" name="phonet" id="phonet" value="<?php echo ContactPhone ;?>:" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Phone:'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Phone:' ) this.value=''">
                <textarea cols="1" rows="1" name="massaget" id="massaget" onBlur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Message:'" onFocus="if(this.value =='Message:' ) this.value=''">Message:</textarea>
                <button id="submit" class="buttonmh">
                    <?php echo SendMessage ;?>
                </button>
</form>
```

shut of email http://designak.ir/Untitled.jpg 
send.php http://designak.ir/send.txt

Comment: check your js code... what's "#contact-formm" ??

Comment: please edit this code for me

Comment: And where is send.php code? Please try to make order in your question is almost a mess now.

Comment: just meaning that "contact-formm" does not exist! (double "m" mistake)

Comment: did you try displaying something in console? add an "error" part in your ajax, and console.log("success") or "error" on success/error to see where you're actually stucked...

Comment: send,php it here http://designak.ir/send.txt

Comment: this screenshot of email http://designak.ir/Untitled.jpg

Comment: If the provided answer solves your issue, please select it as the most helpful answer and also give it an up-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the fields [object HTMLInputElement] error

That is what happens when you take an `<input>` and try to convert it into a string.

You need to read its value and use that instead of the element itself.

```
'namet=' + namet.value // etc
```

You should also escape user input before slapping it into a URL.

```
'namet=' + encodeURIComponent(namet.value) // etc
```